# Add Null value to listbox on Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, null, listbox

In Excel 2016 the following error occurs when trying to add a Null recordset value to a listbox:

[image]

```vb
    With LiBxCliFor
     
     .ColumnCount = 4
     .ColumnHeads = False
     .ColumnWidths = "40;250;120;40"
     
     LinhaLiBx = .ListCount
     
     While Not lrs.EOF
     
     .AddItem
     
     .List(LinhaLiBx, 0) = lrs.Fields("ID_CliFor")
     .List(LinhaLiBx, 1) = lrs.Fields("Nome")
     .List(LinhaLiBx, 2) = lrs.Fields("NumDocumento")
     .List(LinhaLiBx, 3) = lrs.Fields("LocalVenda")
     
     LinhaLiBx = LinhaLiBx + 1
     lrs.MoveNext
     Wend
    End With
```

Error happens on that line as the value is null:

[image: https://www.linkpicture.com/q/imagem_2021-07-05_093138.png]

I developed all my code on Office Professional Plus 2019. The listbox accepts the Null value, but my client is using Office Professional Plus 2016 on his home machine. (Another version in his office is not getting any error.)

Was there an update on Office 2019 to accept Null?

Answer (score 2):

You should try and make your code work on both versions of Excel. This would be one way:-

```
Dim V As Variant

V = lrs.Fields("LocalVenda")
.List(LinhaLiBx, 3) = IIf(IsNull(V), "", V)
```

A shorter way might be ("might" because I didn't test) to precede the assignment with `On Error Resume Next` which I expect would simply leave the list item blank when the error occurs.

Comment: `""` = `vbNullString` • Actually I would prefer testing for null over error silencing (which might come with side effects and make the whole thing un-debug-able).

Comment: I made it a habbit to retrieve field values from string colums like this: `sMyString = vbNullString & lrs.Fields("LocalVenda").Value`. That circumvents both the actual error and any If/Then/Else or On Error shenanigans.